# Format Exception:String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, winforms, datetime

hi I have method for getting the values form database and representing those values in chart controls..

and this is the method...

```
      public static void Hourlyattendence(System.DateTime startdate, System.DateTime enddate, string StartHour, string EndHour,
                                           out string[] Hours, out int[] Accepted, out int[] Refused)
     {
         int hours = 1 + int.Parse(EndHour) - int.Parse(StartHour);

         Hours = new string[hours];
         Accepted = new int[hours];
         Refused = new int[hours];

         int result = 0;

         for (int i = 0; i < hours; i++)
         {
             Accepted[i] = 0;
             Refused[i] = 0;
             Hours[i] = string.Format("{0:00}", int.Parse(StartHour) + i);
         }

         const string sql = @"SELECT COUNT('x') AS numVisits, visit_Status as Status, SUBSTRING(visit_Time,1,2) as visitHour
                              FROM visits
                              WHERE visit_Date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
                              AND SUBSTRING(visit_Time,1,2) between @StartHour and @EndHour
                              GROUP BY SUBSTRING(visit_Time,1,2), visit_Status";

         var hourstable = new DataTable();

         using (var conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
         {
             conn.Open();

             var cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(sql, conn);

             var ds = new DataSet();
             var parameter = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@startdate", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime);
             parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
             parameter.Value = startdate;
             cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);

             var parameter2 = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@enddate", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime);
             parameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
             parameter2.Value = enddate;
             cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter2);

             var parameter3 = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@StartHour", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime);
             parameter3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
             parameter3.Value = StartHour;
             cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter3);

             var parameter4 = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@EndHour", MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDbType.DateTime);
             parameter4.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
             parameter4.Value = EndHour;
             cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter4);

             var da = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

             da.Fill(ds);
             try
             {
                 hourstable = ds.Tables[0];

             }
             catch
             {
                 hourstable = null;
             }
         }
         if (hourstable != null)
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < hourstable.Rows.Count; i++)
             {
                 if (int.TryParse(hourstable.Rows[i]["numVisits"].ToString(), out result) && int.TryParse(hourstable.Rows[i]["visitHour"].ToString(), out hours))
                 {
                     hours -= int.Parse(StartHour);
                     if (hourstable.Rows[i]["Status"].ToString().ToUpper() == "ACCEPTED")
                     {
                         Accepted[hours] = result;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         Refused[hours] = result;
                     }
                 }

             }

         }

     }
```

and i am  calling above method in the below code ...and this is where i am representing the data in chart controls....

```
    private void KpiHourlAttendenceForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Drawkpihourlyattendence(dtpStartDate.Value, dtpEnddate.Value);
    }

    public void Drawkpihourlyattendence(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)
    {
        try
        {
            KpiHourlyattaendencechart.Series.Clear();

            Series acceptedSeries = KpiHourlyattaendencechart.Series.Add("Accepted");
            Series rejectedSeries = KpiHourlyattaendencechart.Series.Add("Refused");

            string[] xValues;
            int[] yValues;
            int[] yValues2;

            KpiData.Hourlyattendence(startdate, enddate, "06", "22", out xValues, out yValues, out yValues2);

            //blah
           //blah
           ///blah
       }
       catch(FormatException e)
      {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

       }
```

**got the exception : format Exception String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

would any one pls help on this.....

Many Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to change the parameter type for `@StartHour` and `@EndHour` because they are string.

Answer (score 1):

Change start/end hour to integer SQL parameter types and cast the SUBSTRING(visit_Time,1,2) to an integer in the line you do your BETWEEN @StartHour and @EndHour

Answer (score 1):

`StartHour` and `EndHour` are not `DateTime`.

Additionally, as @Ryan Wright pointed out, your `between` filter isn't going to work as expected with strings.